RichTextBox is not editable after file is chosen in OpenFileDialog
I'm filling two textfields with filepaths after I chose an input-file. I want the textfield to still be editable, so that the name of the ouput file can be changed, e.g. if the file already exists. The textfields are writable before a file is chosen, but not anymore after that. I checked the ReadOnly property, but it's set to false at all times.
The behavior happens when I click nothing else, so I can't imagine another part of the code interferes with the TextBox.
This doesn't occur with a normal TextBox, but those are ugly :)
Part of my code:
# Create a Select Input TextBox
$SelectInputTextField = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$SelectInputTextField.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point([int]($spacer*2+$commonElementWidth), $spacer)
$SelectInputTextField.AutoSize = $false
$SelectInputTextField.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($widerElementWidth, $commonElementHeight)
$SelectInputTextField.BackColor = "#FFFFFF"
$SelectInputTextField.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14)
$SelectInputTextField.WordWrap = $false
$SelectInputTextField.ReadOnly = $false
$form.Controls.Add($SelectInputTextField)

# Create a Select Input Button
$SelectInputButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SelectInputButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point([int]($spacer*3+$commonElementWidth+$widerElementWidth), $spacer)
$SelectInputButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($commonElementWidth, $commonElementHeight)
$SelectInputButton.Text = "Open"
$SelectInputButton.Add_Click({
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Title = "Select Input File"
    $openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $PSScriptRoot
    if ($openFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $SelectInputTextField.Text = $openFileDialog.FileName
        $outputFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($openFileDialog.FileName) + "\SQL-Code.txt"
        $SelectOutputTextField.Text = $outputFilePath
        $SelectInputTextField.Select($SelectInputTextField.Text.Length, 0)
        $SelectInputTextField.ScrollToCaret()
        $SelectInputTextField.ReadOnly = $false
        $SelectOutputTextField.Select($SelectOutputTextField.Text.Length, 0)
        $SelectOutputTextField.ScrollToCaret()
        $SelectOutputTextField.ReadOnly = $false
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($SelectInputButton)

Edit: This seems to only occur when the script is started from psIDE. I have no problems when running the script from VSCode.

If it happens only in ISE and not with VSCode / normal CLI then what are you expecting for an answer? Don't use ISE, that thing is dinosaur era...

I like dinosaurs.
I guess I'll change to solved.

It's not about liking or not, it's about getting the best development experience and ISE simply does not provide that in addition to bugs like the one you're experiencing

It was a joke, relax.

Simple answer: don't use powershellIDE. Use VScode or any other IDE.
